# Deal with POP3 to creating new folder and get all unread mails

Tags: java, api, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to create New Folder for copying read messages. And also suggest for getting unread mails.I tried all possible ways like (getUnreadMessageCount(),

```
Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, read);
return emailFolder.search(unseenFlagTerm);
```

)
Help me out on this.
Thanks !

Comment: What exactly isnt working? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: i am not able to create new Folder for move receive mails and tried to set Flag SEEN but its not working. My requirements to process only Unread emails.

Answer (score 0):

The POP3 protocol supports exactly one folder - Inbox.  You really want to use IMAP if at all possible.  More details about POP3 in the [com.sun.mail.pop3 package javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).

Comment: NO, i don't want go with IMAP, wants to deal with only UNREAD mails under POP3.

Comment: Thanks ! Bill Shannon